# Is there an alternative for TotalFinder's Visor Feature in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, finder

Is there an alternative for [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com)’s Visor feature? The Visor feature is a keyboard shortcut that brings up a “Finder” window over top of the screen, even on full screen apps.

I don’t want to use all of TotalFinder, because I prefer default Mac OS X “Finder,” but I wish it had a keyboard shortcut to show a finder window over top of full screen apps.

Answer (score 3):

Like you, I was also searching for a TotalFinder alternative, since TotalFinder now requires to disable permanently `System Integrity Protection`, starting from Mojave.

As I didn't find any good alternative, I've finally ended developing a small app that just does what Visor did.

Here is the result :

[image: FastFinder demo]

It is not perfect, as it is done with AppleScript API, but it does the job.

You can download from my GitHub project here : [FastFinder](https://github.com/AnthoPakPak/FastFinder). It's open source and contribution is more than welcomed :)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) with a trigger: ⌥`

```
Show/Hide Finder
Triggered by any of the following:
The Hot Key ⌥` is pressed
Will execute the following actions:
Activate Finder
If already at the front, hide the application.
```

It doesn’t have that fancy animation that will slide “Finder” up but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using an Alfred [hotkey triggered workflow](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/triggers/hotkey/creating-a-hotkey-workflow/) to bring up Path Finder (another Finder alternative) whenever I hit: ⌥`

It works fine for bringing the app into focus and even launching it if need be, but unlike TotalFinder's Visor feature, Path Finder does not pop up "over any desktop" (OS X will slide you back to the desktop the app is open in if need be). I guess that this would be the same functionality via Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: I just tried the Keyboard Maestro macro suggested by @Patrick Thompson and it seems better than my Alfred workflow, mainly because it does a better job of toggling the app in question (show/hide). I just read up a bit more and it seems that Keyboard Maestro is unable to affect which Desktop/Space an app appears in so this aspect is a bit of a compromise compared to TotalFinder's Visor. More info: https://wiki.keyboardmaestro.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_can_I_move_an_application_or_window_to_a_particular_DesktopSpace

Answer (score 0):

I use the following simple AppleScript to "emulate" the visor behavior with a normal Finder window.

```
if visible of application "Finder" is false then
    activate application "Finder"
else
    tell application "Finder"
        set visible to false
    end tell
end if
```

You can then link this code to some hotkey (for example with Keyboard Maestro). Make sure that the Finder window is not linked to any particular desktop/space, i.e., set the option "all spaces" for the window. This should make sure that the same Finder window pops up on any desktop/space.